# Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name in codeigniter 4

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation

I am trying to set a form validation rule. It says Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Customer (validate_customer). Any help on that would be appreciated.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_id', 'Customer' ,'required|callback_validate_customer');
```

And this is my validation methond.

```
function validate_customer() {
if((double)$this->input->post('paid_amount') == 0)
{
   $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_customer' , 'Can not sale.');
   return FALSE;
} else {
   return TRUE;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These methods are `set_message`, `form_validation` and `callback_` no more in Codeigniter 4. For this, you need to use a [custom rule](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/validation.html?highlight=form#creating-custom-rules).

Example:

```
<?php
namespace App\Validation;

class CustomRules{
    public function customerValidation( ... , array $data)){

    }  
}
```

And use it like

```
"customer_id" => "required|customerValidation[customer_id]"
```

Check these

1. [Creating Custom Rules](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/validation.html?highlight=form#creating-custom-rules)
2. [How to Create Custom Validation Rule in CodeIgniter 4](https://onlinewebtutorblog.com/how-to-create-custom-validation-rule-in-codeigniter-4/)

Comment: Thanks Abdulla. I got it for CI 4. But I got the same error message on CI 3.1.4. Could you please help me on that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this code works for me.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
                'customer_id', 'Customer',
                'required|min_length[1]|max_length[12]|customer_due_check',
                array(
                        'required'      => 'You have not provided %s.',
                        'customer_due_check'     => 'This %s already exists.'
                )
        );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).